# In MySQL how can I make all possible set / groups of different status values in a table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

Can anyone help me to sort out this problem using query/procedure/functions.

```
id   Price   Status
--   -----   ------
1    10      1
2    12      1
3    15      2
4    21      3
5    25      1
6    27      2
7    32      2
8    10      3
9    08      3
10   11      1
```

### Expected Result

I want all possible set/combination of rows with different status and want total sum of price.

#### Eg:

- Id: 1, 3, 4 can be combined since they all have different status.

#### //output

```
id      price   status
-----   -----   ------
1,3,4   46      1,2,3
2,6,8   49      1,2,3
5,7,9   65      1,2,3
```

**Record for Id: 10** will not be displayed since one can't create a complete set with all different status available in database.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. Please consider reading the following article: _[How do I ask a good question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (Help Centre)_. Currently your question has some open ends and might be closed as [**unclear what you're asking**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). For example, why not `1, 6, 7 -> 69 -> 1, 2, 3`? What is the logic for grouping `1, 3, 4` and not any other combination? Thanks for taking your time and adding as much details as possible by [editing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/214535/edit) your question.

Comment: Why can't you group `7,9,10`? Do they have to be in order?

Comment: Here I want to pick records on the basis of ID ASC that's why I mentioned this example.
There are many other Possible scenarios to create a set / combination of all different values of status.
1, 6, 7 and 7,8,9 are also possible. One more thing if status has 4 different values then we'll make set of 4 records.
Please share if you have any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draft code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc
BEGIN
DECLARE CURSOR cur1 FOR SELECT id, price FROM table WHERE status=1 ORDER BY id;
DECLARE CURSOR cur2 FOR SELECT id, price FROM table WHERE status=2 ORDER BY id;
DECLARE CURSOR cur3 FOR SELECT id, price FROM table WHERE status=3 ORDER BY id;
SET @done := 0;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET @done := 1;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS combinations;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE combinations (id INT, price DECIMAL(15,6)) ENGINE = Memory;
OPEN cur1;    OPEN cur2;    OPEN cur3;
cycle: WHILE 1
    FETCH cur1 INTO @id1,@price1;
    FETCH cur2 INTO @id2,@price2;
    FETCH cur3 INTO @id3,@price3;
    IF @done THEN
        LEAVE cycle
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO combinations(id,price) 
        VALUES (CONCAT_WS(',',@id1,@id2,@id3),@price1+@price2+@price3);
END WHILE;
CLOSE cur1;    CLOSE cur2;    CLOSE cur3;
SELECT * FROM combinations;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE combinations;
END;
```

**UPDATE**

A single-query solution that automatically determines the number of different statuses:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(xxx.id ORDER BY xxx.status) ids, 
       SUM(xxx.price) totalsum,  
       GROUP_CONCAT(xxx.status ORDER BY xxx.status) statuses
FROM (SELECT ta.*,
             IF(@typex=ta.status,
                @rownum:=@rownum+1,
                @rownum:=1+LEAST(0,@typex:=ta.status)) AS rown
      FROM test ta, (SELECT @rownum:=1, @typex:='_') x
      ORDER BY status, id) xxx,
     (SELECT rown, COUNT(rown)
      FROM (SELECT ta.*,
                   IF(@typex=ta.status,
                      @rownum:=@rownum+1,
                      @rownum:=1+least(0,@typex:=ta.status)) AS rown
            FROM test ta, (SELECT @rownum:=1, @typex:='_') x
            ORDER BY status, id
           ) xx
      GROUP BY rown
      ORDER BY 2 DESC, 1 DESC
      LIMIT 1) xxxx
WHERE xxx.rown <= xxxx.rown
GROUP BY xxx.rown;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=090daaea7dacf34fa369c5c5979c9681)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I've only one doubt, in my scenario status values can be different upto ....n numbers (eg:1,2,3,4 ...10). In that case I've to create a set of all different values (like: 1,2,3,4 ....n). In your case it seems that it'll make set of only 3 different values.
Can you please give me an idea how I can achieve that.

Sorry for my mistake, I didn't describe the whole scenarios.

Comment: A cycle of prepared statements instead of fixed pack of similar queries.

Comment: I've very new in Mysql Procedures so your help will be much appreciable.
Can you please provide me a small ex script for prepared statement?

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: In monday... phone is not safe for long texts.

Comment: You are really a champ. I used your procedure by which I got solution approx 60-70 % the only problem was with "n" of status. I try with your query. I also posted another query here. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/214672/mysql-sql-query-procedure-to-get-accumulated-rooms-for-each-hotel-on-the-basi